# Ploting time series with ggplot2 qplot function

Tags: r, time, ggplot2

I need to have a plot and a time series of 24 hours with 5 minutes interval. I used the qplot function.

I get the variable for the time like this:

```
intervals <- seq(ISOdatetime(2001,2,3,0,0,0), 
                      ISOdatetime(2001,2,4,0,0,0), by=(60*5))

intervals <- intervals[1:length(intervals)-1]
intervals <- strftime(intervals, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

the last line I used just to have the time.

When I plot it looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to have the hours displayed in the x axis, instead of what I have. Can you help me with that?

Thank you

Thanks to Paulo I did manage to get the rigth plot using:

`ggplot(act_weekdays, aes(x=interval, y=steps)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~day) + scale_x_datetime(breaks = pretty_breaks(), minor_breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"), labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + xlab("Interval") + ylab("Number of steps")`

Giving me this graph:

http://s25.postimg.org/828ypjkqn/Rplot01.png

Comment: where did you use qplot? why not just use ggplot? qplot is just a dumbed down version of ggplot

Comment: and what about your data?

Comment: I am using this: qplot(interval, steps, data = plot_dataset, facets = .~ days, type = "l")

Comment: Sorry the data was too in here: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
intervals <- seq(ISOdatetime(2001,2,3,0,0,0), 
                 ISOdatetime(2001,2,4,0,0,0), by=(60*5))

intervals <- intervals[1:length(intervals)-1]
d <- data.frame(steps=rep(rnorm(288, 100, 6), 2),
                int = rep(intervals, 2),
                period = rep(c('weekday', 'weekend'), each = 144, times = 2))
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(d, aes(x=int, y=steps)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(.~period) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = pretty_breaks(),
                   minor_breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: ggplot]

or

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=int, y=steps)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(.~period) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = pretty_breaks(),
                   minor_breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: hour:minutes]

The code above works with the data I'm providing and the system spec

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] scales_0.2.4  ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.0       gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.2    
 [6] MASS_7.3-33      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2     
[11] reshape2_1.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0
```

RStudio Version 0.98.932

Comment: Thank you Paulo, but I am still getting an error:

Before it was saying that didn't found the function pretty_breaks, but I think I solved that by install the package prettyR

Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

Comment: It works for me without any other package or change. Did you try with the exact example above? R and RStudio versions?

Comment: Thank you Paulo! I did manage to get the plot I wanted using:

ggplot(act_weekdays, aes(x=interval, y=steps)) + 
    geom_point() + facet_grid(.~day) + scale_x_datetime(breaks = pretty_breaks(),
                                                        minor_breaks = date_breaks("2 hour"),
                                                        labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + xlab("Interval") + 
    ylab("Number of steps")

Answer (score 0):

Nice. I solved a similar problem using scales_x_continuous. The link below explains why this is a more proper way, using the chron package, i.e. you need not include an arbitrary year, month and date in the interval when mixing time-related data from several days: http://ggplot2.tumblr.com/

Here is an example using traffic data: km/h and time of day. I imported data from a speadsheet. The time data became a string, e.g. 7:12:07, which I changed to proper time data like this:   t2$time <- times(t2$time).

```
tp<-ggplot(t2)+ aes(x=time,y=speed) + geom_point(size=2) 
tp <- tp  + xlab('time') + ylab('km/h') + ggtitle('Speed and time')
tp <- tp + scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks()(range(t2$time)),minor_breaks = times(c(1:23)/24))
tp + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1:10)*10)
```